# I can't execute a website using blazor webassembly published on IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, publish, webassembly

I created a project with Blazor Webassembly using SignalR (VS 2019 - .Net Core 3.1).
When I run it from the development environment it works correctly, but when I publish it to IIS (the server project) and I try to run it, it shows me the following message:

Loading...
An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

The messages in the console are:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.css:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
blazor.webassembly.js:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.css:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.css:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.css:1

Comment: Did you enable web sockets on iis?

Comment: check your basehref and network log

Comment: When you receive  the server responded with a status of 404. There should be a 404 error in your developer tool network tab. Please check whether your application is requesting css from correct URL. Besides, please ensure IIS static content feature has been installed. It is appreciated if you could provide more details espcially sub-status code or event viewer.

Comment: Indeed, href had to be corrected. Once the correct value was set the page started working. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the same resolution resolved it for me!

What I did was browse to the website where I hosted it, went into developer mode of the browser (F12), hovered over the error and looked at the path!

In my index.html file I had  in the and just needed to remove the forward slash  and it started working just fine!